# Select columns names of the SELECT statement

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have some select statements, one of them:

```
SELECT c_c.id,
       c_c.full_name,
       c_c.telephone,
       c_c.fax,
       cast(c_c.adress_juridical as varchar(256)) as adress_juridical,
       cast(c_c.adress_naturale as varchar(256)) as adress_naturale,
       c_c.director,     
       c_c.name,
       c_c.b_id,
       c_c.dt_start,
       c_c.dt_end       
FROM c_counteragents c_c  
WHERE c_c.id = -1 AND c_c.b_id = -1;
```

How can I get names of select statement?
The names of columns of this select must be without allias `c_c`.
It's not so easy, just to take a table name and find table's columns names. I don't know the name of table, because I retrieve this `SELECT` statement from some table, where it stores as a text.

Comment: Do you mean you need output for id like c_counteragents.id in column header?

Comment: One method is to use the query to create a view and then use the column names in `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns`.

Comment: What language and client driver are you using? PostgreSQL reports this information in the `Describe` message response in the v3 wire protocol, but as far as I know there's no way you can get it from the SQL level. You'd need to use your client driver's metadata functions. PgJDBC exposes this information, I don't know if many/any other drivers do.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name   = 'c_counteragents' ORDER BY ordinal_position` but you need the name of the table.